# could not find function "summary.rbga"

Tags: r

when im trying to execute the the following command:

> cat(summary.rbga(GAmodel))

the output is:

Error in cat(summary.rbga(GAmodel)):

could not find function "summary.rbga"

im sure that i import the package by the command "library(genalg)" and it works perfectly for other functions.
im using Version 0.98.1102 on windows.

Answer (score 8):

The function `summary.rbga` is in `genalg` but it's not exported from the package explicitly. It's the special implementation of the `summary` function  for `rbga` objects. In the example from the help page, you can see how it works

```
evaluate <- function(string=c()) {
    returnVal = 1 / sum(string);
    returnVal
}

rbga.results = rbga.bin(size=10, mutationChance=0.01, zeroToOneRatio=0.5,
    evalFunc=evaluate)

class(rbga.results)
# [1] "rbga"

summary(rbga.results, echo=TRUE)
# GA Settings
#   Type                  = binary chromosome
#   Population size       = 200
#   Number of Generations = 100
#   Elitism               = 40
#   Mutation Chance       = 0.01
# 
# Search Domain
#   Var 1 = [,]
#   Var 0 = [,]
# 
# GA Results
#   Best Solution : 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Note that you call `summary` rather than `summary.rbga` directly. As long as you pass in an object that has class "rbga" it will work.

You can access the function directly with `genalg:::summary.rbga`